# Ubuntu Cross-compile for ARM - PATH variable - bash error

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, gcc, cross-compilation

I have downloaded CodeSourcery Toolchain tools located to the following path:

root@ab-pc:~/arm-2009q1/bin#

arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-c++
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-c++filt
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.3.3
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcov
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdb

and I have exported this path to my PATH variable:

root@ab-pc:~# echo $PATH
/root/arm-2009q1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

but when I execute the command: 
root@ab-pc:~# arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v

-bash: /root/arm-2009q1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: No such file or directory

However Which command shows: 
root@ab-pc:~# which arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
/root/arm-2009q1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and why I take this error?

Many thanks!

Comment: At a *guess* the arm-none-linux-gnueabi-xxx tools are 32-bit ELF binaries and you have a 64-bit OS

Comment: Hi steeldriver, yes you are right. Thats true, but I am trying to cross-compile for a 32-bit ARM arch. So, how I can fix this? Need a 32-bit OS?

Comment: Try adding the libc6-x32 package to get the 32 bit loader.

Comment: You *may* be able to install the necessary 32-bit libraries to make it work - if you see [How to install the ARM toolchain?](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/toolchain/arm/install/) and scroll down to `GNU/Linux` for example it suggests `lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`